# Vim copy paste adding newlines

Tags: linux, vim

Vim is adding lots of spaces and newlines when copy / pasting.  This is what it looks like:

[image: http://i.imm.io/vEiu.jpeg]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to copy and past the code onto another editor, and see if the new empty lines appear?

Comment: @Zuul The same happens in nano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gedit is using 4 spaces per indent, your VIM looks like it's using 8 spaces per indent.

There's nothing wrong, just a simple setting difference.

Look up the options:

- shiftwidth
- softtabstop
- tabstop
- expandtab

---

```
:set sw=4 sts=4 ts=8 et
```

will make your VIM look like your Gedit.

Comment: My gedit is not using spaces, only tabs.

Comment: I understand that.... and your gedit is EMULATING a tab with 4 spaces... while vim is doing the same with the default 8.  A tab is a tab is a tab... until you display it and it is parsed by the output routine.  gedit is using 4 character widths, while vim is using 8.  The settings I showed will fix it.

Comment: I tried it, but it turned tabs into spaces, which I don't want. And the newlines are still there.

Comment: oh, sorry, make that a 'noet' rather then 'et', to each his own.  The newlines are likely from gedit and the 'set paste' option, and if you copy/pasted this from a website, it probably has BOTH cr & lf (from windows!), which causes the double cr on linux.  gedit got the original paste, so it handled the dos/windows line endings.  vim is getting an anonymous paste, so it has to handle what it gets, there's no clues.

Comment: Yep, seems like there was some crazy characters in the file. I rewrote it and now it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're pasting from the clipboard or something? Try `:set paste` before pasting.

The first thing I do on any new machine is put `set paste` in my vimrc.  I prefer paste mode as the default behaviour.

Edit:
And you can use `:set nopaste` to turn paste mode off and the auto-format back on.

Comment: It didn't work. Now it says 'INSERT (paste)' but the pasted text looks the same. I'm copying text from gedit, then pasting into vim.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange.  Only time I have seen that type of behaviour is when not in paste mode, if the encoding is "special" (UTF8/16, etc), or if a vim plugin/script is causing the issue.

Answer (score 5):

you probably have vim's autoindent mode on.  try turning it off with `:set noautoindent`

also, as mentioned by CR above, `:set paste` greatly improves vim's behaviour while pasting text into it...with paste mode set you don't need to mess around manually setting text-width, wrap-margin or anything else likely to mess up long lines or text spacing.  remember to use `:set nopaste` when you've finished pasting.